# Basic Authentication on Glassfish using Ldap

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, glassfish, ldap

I´m developping a Web Service. Currently, I´m using Basic Authentication using a file to manage users.

Now I want to use Basic authentication, integrate LDAP server. I installed and I create a LDAP server, using LDAP - Apache Directory Studio.

In Glassfish console I create a new ldapRealm.

My web.xml has this code:

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>LDAP</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Now I want to specify different roles for different ldap group of users.

How can I achieve this? There is any tutorial for this prupose for Web Services?

There is possiblity to add an annotation specifing roles like @RolesAllowed(LDAP Group) to different methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to configure the realm in Glassfish look [*To Create an LDAP Realm in the GlassFish Server*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0871/gjepj/index.html).

Regarding Apache Directory Studio, see [*Let's create an LDAP user and search for him*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IEZEEpSKtA). You may want to see [*Setting up an LDAP directory server for Alfresco development*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJr1hJVo2So).